# Flutter error on a PageView with GoogleMaps Screen

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, graphql

I have a special isue in Flutter, The case is, in a page with appbar, body, and bottomBar, in the body I have a page view with 3 pages. First one with a map, second and third one with a list of elements.
If change the page second -> third for example, everything goes fine, but when I do it with the GoogleMap page, after jump from one page to the next, all screen in the device turns white for a second, like a rebuild.

Seems like when I change page to another one from map page, the GoogleMaps rebuild all the page. Any idea about this?

Thank you:

```
Doctor: 
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.19042.1415], locale es-ES)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

'''

```
class _HomeState extends State<PageViewLocalization>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(widget._),
      backgroundColor: Styles.principalBackGroundColor,
      body: PageView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: widget._.localizationPageViewController,
        children: [
          mapExplorationPage(widget._),
          allMapGoogleMapsObservationsPage(widget._),
          allMyGoogleMapsObservationsPage(widget._),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
appBar(HomeController _) {
    return AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      actions: [
        Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: CustomSlidingSegmentedControl(
              fixedWidth: 60,
              padding: 8,
              children: {
                0: Icon(
                  Icons.map_outlined,
                  size: 14,
                  color: _.currentLocalizationPage == 0
                      ? _.enabledCustomSlidingSegmentedControl
                          ? Styles.minkaPrincipalColor
                          : Colors.grey
                      : Colors.grey,
                ),
                1: Icon(
                  Icons.list,
                  size: 14,
                  color: _.currentLocalizationPage == 1
                      ? Styles.minkaPrincipalColor
                      : Colors.grey,
                ),
                2: Icon(
                  Icons.person_outline,
                  size: 14,
                  color: _.currentLocalizationPage == 2
                      ? Styles.minkaPrincipalColor
                      : Colors.grey,
                ),
              },
              onValueChanged: (int value) async {
                if (value != 0 && _.boundsInicialized == false) {
                  _.boundsInicialized = true;
                  _.manager!.onCameraMove(_.cameraPositionOnInicializeMap);
                  await _.showItemsInTheMapCamera(
                      _.cameraPositionOnInicializeMap,
                      _.mapControllerCompleter);
                }

                if (_.enabledCustomSlidingSegmentedControl) {
                  _.currentLocalizationPage = value;
                  _.update();
                  _.localizationPageViewController.jumpToPage(
                    _.currentLocalizationPage,
                  );
                  // await _.localizationPageViewController.animateToPage(
                  //     _.currentLocalizationPage,
                  //     curve: Curves.easeIn,
                  //     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: Styles.paddingValue / 2)
      ],
      backgroundColor: Styles.principalBackGroundColor,
      elevation: Styles.defaultElevation,
      title: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: Styles.paddingValue / 2),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            "assets/images/ic_1231232.svg",
            width: 108,
            height: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 mapExplorationPage(HomeController _) {
    Completer<GoogleMapController> _passInfoCompleter = Completer();

    return SizedBox(
      child: GoogleMap(
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _.cameraPositionOnInicializeMap,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          if (!_.mapControllerCompleter.isCompleted) {
            mapController = controller;
            _.mapControllerCompleter.complete(controller);
            _.manager!.setMapId(controller.mapId);
            await _.showItemsInTheMapCamera(
                _.cameraPositionOnInicializeMap, _.mapControllerCompleter);
          } else {
            _passInfoCompleter.complete(controller);
            _.mapControllerCompleter = _passInfoCompleter;
            _.manager!.setMapId(controller.mapId);
          }
          // _.zoomEfect();
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        markers: _.markers,
        onCameraIdle: _.manager!.updateMap,
        onCameraMove: (position) async {
          if (_.mapControllerCompleter.isCompleted) {
            if (_.markers.isEmpty) {
              _.fillAllMarkers();
            }
            _.manager!.onCameraMove(position);
            await _.showItemsInTheMapCamera(position, _.mapControllerCompleter);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

'''

VIDEO:
[Yo can see, when I go from map page to another one, a white screen refresh all the aplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AddAI.gif)

Comment: Thanks Brad! I see the coment after the correction, I'm sorry about it

Answer (score 0):

Try separating your `mapExplorationPage` & `allMyGoogleMapsObservationsPage` & `allMapGoogleMapsObservationsPage` widgets into separate widgets and add the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to each one of them as it should be added to the page view widgets instead of the parent home widget

1)

```dart
class MapExplorationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapExplorationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapExplorationPageState createState() => _MapExplorationPageState();
}

class _MapExplorationPageState extends State<MapExplorationPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    // ...
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

2. 

```dart
class AllMapGoogleMapsObservationsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllMapGoogleMapsObservationsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AllMapGoogleMapsObservationsPageState createState() => _AllMapGoogleMapsObservationsPageState();
}

class _AllMapGoogleMapsObservationsPageState extends State<AllMapGoogleMapsObservationsPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    // ...
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

3. 

```dart
class AllMyGoogleMapsObservationsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllMyGoogleMapsObservationsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AllMyGoogleMapsObservationsPageState createState() => _AllMyGoogleMapsObservationsPageState();
}

class _AllMyGoogleMapsObservationsPageState extends State<AllMyGoogleMapsObservationsPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    // ...
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Side note, separating widget into their own widgets rather than creating build methods is strongly recommended for performance and code readability so always try to do that. [Check out this video from the Flutter about this issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo)

Comment: Hi Roaa, thank you for your help!I tryed your idea but the problem persists.

I need to explain, In my project I have a homePage, inside this one, I have a pageView with 5 Pages. ( X, MapLocations, X, X ,X ).  In mapLocations I have the current PageView Problem with the map.

So it's a PageView, Inside a PageView. maybe with this info is more easy to find a solution. 

For the moment, I divided the pageviews in withgets in homePage and in the MapLocation how you said, but the white window persists when I change the pageMapView screen. Any other idea?

Thank you so much again!

Comment: Can you please add a screen recording of what's happening in the question?

Comment: Yes roaa, I just added a gif with the problem!